# How to set a Django model field's NoData value

Tags: python, django, model

I just realized that the dataset I uploaded to Django model has a field (call it 'A') with "-999" which indicates NoData. This is throwing off my calculations, but I don't want to totally exclude these objects from my filters, just for calculations, for example: objects.aggregate(Avg('A')).

How do I tell my Django model to treat this value as the NoData for field A? I see null=True tells Django to store empty values as NoData, but what if it should store Null when the values = -999.

If there is not a straightforward way, is the best/most efficient way just to use exclude() whenever I make these calculations? Or maybe I should do some sort of replace in my database to convert -999 in field A to Null (how?). I thank you

Comment: As I was reading your question I was thinking _"You probably want to use `exclude()`"_ and then I got to the last sentence.   This is probably the fastest way to calculate the average, however if you want to reduce the load on your database   then you should filter (exclude) and evaluate the queryset and iterate over it, calculating the running total and the number of objects to get the average in python rather than the DB.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to use `exclude` in your aggregate queries:

```
YourModel.objects.exclude(a=-999).aggregate(Avg('a'))
```

If you wanted to replace the -999 values with `None`:

1. Adjust your Model field with the correct parameters (e.g.: null=True)
2. Do a schema migration
3. Do a [Data Migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

The data migration would need to call a function something like:

```
def update_nodata(apps, schema_editor):
    YourModel = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'YourModel')
    for obj in YourModel.objects.filter(a=-999):
        obj.a = None
        obj.save()
```